# Python script not really executing

Tags: python

I'm using the latest spyder/anaconda (Python 3.8) software and a beginner here. When running a simple hello.py script. I get `runfile('C:/Users/Raj/CODE/Python Scripts/hello.py', wdir='C:/Users/Raj/CODE/Python Scripts')` but nothing else in the console or anywhere saying "Hello World".

```py
def hello():
    """Print "Hello World" and return None."""
    print("Hello World")
```

It can do other print type scripts just fine as I tried an old script from college.

Comment: Because you haven't _called_ the function, so none of the code that is in the function body will execute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 1):

Any function needs to be called in order to get executed. You call a function by typing it's name with the (), in your case hello()

Answer (score 1):

on bottom of the python file add the call to the function hello

```
hello()
```